# Sudoku solving class in PHP

Tags: php, php5, sudoku

Here is my PHP class for solving Sudoku:

[GitHub](https://gist.github.com/889044)

**Sudoku**

```
<?php

/**
* Bootstrap file
*
* This is an example of how to use the SudokuSolver Class
* Here the input array has been hardcoded. It could be send
* as get or post in the real application.
*
* @author Anush Prem <goku.anush@gmail.com>
* @package Solver
* @subpackage Sudoku
* @version 0.1
*/

/**
* Required Class files
*/
include_once "SudokuSolver.class.php";

// The application could take longer than normal php execution
// time. So set the execution time limit to 0(unlimited).
set_time_limit(0);

// input sudoku array in the format row == col array mapping
$sudoku = array(
array(0,4,0,0,5,3,1,0,2),
array(2,0,8,1,0,0,7,0,0),
array(5,0,1,4,2,0,6,0,0),
array(8,1,4,0,3,0,2,0,7),
array(0,6,0,2,0,5,0,1,9),
array(0,5,0,7,4,0,0,6,3),
array(0,0,0,0,7,4,5,8,1),
array(1,8,5,9,0,2,0,0,0),
array(4,0,3,0,0,8,0,2,6)
);

// create an object of SudokuSolver.
$solver = new SudokuSolver();

// Pass the input sudoku to the $solver object.
$solver -> input ($sudoku);

// Solve the sudoku and return the solved sudoku.
$solved = $solver -> solve ();

// printing the formated input sudoku
print "<B>Input Sudoku:</B><br />";
foreach ($sudoku as $row){
foreach ($row as $col ){
print $col . "&nbsp;&nbsp;";
}
print "<br />";
}

print "<hr />";

// printing the formated solved sudoku.
print "<B>Solved Sudoku:</B><br />";
foreach ($solved as $row){
foreach ($row as $col ){
print $col . "&nbsp;&nbsp;";
}
print "<br />";
}
?>
```

**Sudoku Solver**

```
<?php

/**
* @author Anush Prem <goku.anush@gmail.com>
* @package Solver
* @subpackage Sudoku
* @version 0.1
*/

/**
* <i>Sudoku Solver</i> class
*
* This class solves the sudoku in my own logic.
*
* This solver takes time to execute according to the
* complexity of the sudoku.
*
* @author Anush Prem <goku.anush@gmail.com>
* @package Solver
* @subpackage Sudoku
* @version 0.1
*/

Class SudokuSolver{

/**
* To store the input Sudoku
* @access private
* @var array $_input row == column mapping
*/
private $_input;

/**
* To store the currently solved sudoku at any moment of time
* @access private
* @var array $_currentSudoku row == column mapping
*/
private $_currentSudoku;

/**
* To store the probable values for each cell
* @access private
* @var array $_probable [row][col] == possible values array mapping
*/
private $_probable;

/**
* to store weather the sudoku have been solved or not
* @access private
* @var bool
*/
private $_solved = false;

/**
* store weather each cell is solved or not
* @access private
* @var array $_solvedParts row == column (bool) values
*/
private $_solvedParts = array (
array ( false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false ),
array ( false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false ),
array ( false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false ),
array ( false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false ),
array ( false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false ),
array ( false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false ),
array ( false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false ),
array ( false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false ),
array ( false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false )
);

/**
* SudokuSolver constructor
*
* If the input sudoku is provided it will store to the {@link _input} property.
*
* @access public
* @param array $input row == column mapping
* @return void
*/
public function __construct($input = null){

// check if the input sudoku is provided, if yes then
// store it in $_input
if ( $input !== null ) $this -> _input = $input;
}

/**
* Input Method
*
* Explictly give a new input array if its not already provided in
* the constructor. If already provieded in the constructore then
* it will be replaced
*
* @access public
* @param array $input row == column mapping
* @return void
*/
public function input($input){

// store the received input into $_input
$this -> _input = $input;
}

/**
* Solve Method
*
* The main function to start solving the sudoku and return the
* solved sudoku
*
* @access public
* @return array row == column mapping of solved sudoku
*/
public function solve (){

// Copy the input sudoku to _currentSudoku
$this -> _currentSudoku = $this -> _input;

// update _solvedParts of the given sudoku
$this -> _updateSolved ();

// Start solving the sudoku
$this -> _solveSudoku();

// return the solved sudoku
return $this -> _currentSudoku;
}

/**
* updateSolved Method
*
* Update the _solvedParts array to match the values of
* _currentSudoku.
*
* @access private
* @return void
*/
private function _updateSolved(){

// loop for rows
for ($i = 0; $i < 9; $i++ )

// loop for columns
for ($j = 0; $j < 9; $j++ )

// if the value exists for the corresponding row, column
// then update the _solvedParts corresponding row, column
// to true
if ( $this -> _currentSudoku[$i][$j] != 0 )
$this -> _solvedParts[$i][$j] = true;
}

/**
* _solveSudoku Method
*
* Main sudoku solving method
*
* @access private
* @return void
*/
private function _solveSudoku(){

// continue running untill the sudoku is completly solved
do{
// calculate the probable values for each cell an solve
// available cells
$this -> _calculateProbabilityAndSolve();

// check weather the sudoku is completly solved
$this -> _checkAllSolved();
}while (!$this -> _solved); // run till the _solved value becomes true

}

/**
* _calculateProbabilityAndSolve Method
*
* Find the possible values for each cell and
* solve it if possible
*
* @access private
* @return void
*/
private function _calculateProbabilityAndSolve(){

// find possible values for each cell
$this -> _findPosibilites();

// check if each cell is solveable and if yes solve it
$this -> _solvePossible();

}

/**
* _findPosibilites Method
*
* Find possible values for each cell
*
* @access private
* @return void
*/
private function _findPosibilites(){

// loop for rows
for ($i = 0; $i < 9; $i++ ){

// loop for columns
for ($j = 0; $j < 9; $j++ ){

// if the ixj cell is not solved yet
if ( !$this -> _solvedParts[$i][$j] ){

// find all possible values for cell ixj
$this -> _findAllProbables ($i, $j);
}
}
}
}

/**
* _solvePossible Method
*
* Solve possible cells using probable values calculated
*
* @access private
* @return void
*/
private function _solvePossible(){

// loop for rows
for ($i = 0; $i < 9; $i++ ){

// loop for column
for ($j = 0; $j < 9; $j++ ){

// if cell ixj is not solved yet
if ( !$this -> _solvedParts[$i][$j] ){

// solve the cell ixj if possible using probable values
// calculated
$this -> _solveIfSolveable ($i, $j);
}
}
}
}

/**
* _checkAllSolved Method
*
* check if all the cells have been solved
*
* @access private
* @return void
*/
private function _checkAllSolved(){

// pre assign all solved as true
$allSolved = true;

// loop for rows
for ($i = 0; $i < 9; $i++ ){

// loop for columns
for ($j = 0; $j < 9; $j++ ){

// if allSolved is still true an the cell iXj is not
if ( $allSolved and !$this -> _solvedParts[$i][$j] ){
// set all solved as false
$allSolved = false;
}
}
}

// copy the value of allSolved into _solved.
$this -> _solved = $allSolved;
}

/**
* _solveIfSolveable Method
*
* Solve a single cell $rowx$col if it is solveable using
* available probable datas
*
* @access private
* @param int $row 0-8
* @param int $col 0-8
* @return bool
*/
private function _solveIfSolveable ($row, $col){

// if there is only one probable value for the cell $rowx$col
if ( count ($this -> _probable[$row][$col]) == 1 ){

// copy the only possible value to $value
$value = $this -> _probable[$row][$col][0];

// set the value of cell $rowx$col as $value an update solvedParts
$this -> _setValueForCell ($row, $col, $value);

// return true as solved
return true;
}

// pre assign $value as 0. ie; not solved
$value = 0;

// loop through all the possible values for $row x $col
// and check if any possiblity can be extracted from it
// by checking if its possible for the same number to be
// positioned anywhere else thus confilicting with current
// cell. If a possibility is not a possibility for any other
// cell in the confilicting places then it is the value for
// current cell
foreach ($this -> _probable[$row][$col] as $possible){

// a try-catch exception handling used here
// as a control statement for continuing the main loop
// if a value is possible in some place.
try{

// loop through the current column
for ($i = 0; $i < 9; $i++ ){
// if the cell is solved continue the loop
if ($this -> _currentSudoku[$i][$col] != 0)
continue;

// if the possible is also possible in the $i x $col cell
// then throw a ContinueException to continue the outer loop
if (in_array($possible, $this -> _probable[$i][$col]))
throw new ContinueException ("Exists");

}

// loop through the current row
for ($i = 0; $i < 9; $i++ ){
// if the cell is solved continue the loop
if ($this -> _currentSudoku[$row][$i] != 0)
continue;

// if the possible is also possible in the $i x $col cell
// then throw a ContinueException to continue the outer loop
if (in_array($possible, $this -> _probable[$row][$i]))
throw new ContinueException ("Exists");

}

// find the start of the 3x3 grid with $row x $col cell
$gridRowStart = $this -> _findGridStart($row);
$gridColStart = $this -> _findGridStart($col);

// loop row through the current 3x3 grid
for ($i = $gridRowStart; $i < $gridRowStart + 3; $i++){

// loop column through the current 3x3 gri
for ($j = $gridColStart; $j < $gridColStart + 3; $j++){

// if its the current $row x $col cell then
// continue the loop
if ($i == $row && $j == $col )
continue;

// if the cell is already solved then
// continue the loop
if ($this -> _currentSudoku[$row][$i] != 0)
continue;

// if the possible is also possible in the
// $i x $j cell then throw a ContinueException
// to continue the outer loop
if (in_array($possible, $this -> _probable[$i][$j]))
throw new ContinueException ("Exists");
}
}

// if the loop is not continued yet,
// then that means this possible value is
// not possible in any other conflicting
// cells. So assign the value of $value to
// $possible and break the loop.
$value = $possible;
break;
}catch (ContinueException $e){
// if a ContinueException is thrown then contine
// the outer loop
continue;
}
}

// if the value of $value is not 0 then the value of
// the cell is $value.
if ($value != 0){

// set the value of cell $rowx$col as $value an update solvedParts
$this -> _setValueForCell ($row, $col, $value);

// return true as solved
return true;
}

// return false as not solved yet.
return false;
}

/**
* _setValueForCell Method
*
* If a cell is solved then update the value for
* that cell, and also update the {@link _solvedParts}.
*
* @access private
* @param int $row 0-8
* @param int $col 0-8
* @param int $value 1-9
* @return void
*/
private function _setValueForCell($row, $col, $value){

// update the solved parts in _currentSudoku.
$this -> _currentSudoku[$row][$col] = $value;

// update the corresponding _solvedParts.
$this -> _solvedParts[$row][$col] = true;
}

/**
* _findAllProbables Method
*
* Find all possible values for any given cell using
* other already solved or given cell values.
*
* @access private
* @param int $row 0-8
* @param int $col 0-8
* @return void
*/
private function _findAllProbables ($row, $col){

// initially set the $probable as array 1 to 9.
$probable = range(1,9);

// loop through current column
for ($i = 0; $i < 9; $i++ )

// if the cell $i x $col is solved and the value of
// cell $ix$col is in the $probable array then remove
// that element.
if (
( $current = $this -> _currentSudoku[$i][$col] ) != 0
and
( $key = array_search($current, $probable) ) !== false
)
unset ($probable[$key]);

// loop through the current row
for ($i = 0; $i < 9; $i++ )

// if the cell $row x $i is solved and the value of
// cell $rowx$i is in the $probable array then remove
// that element.
if (
( $current = $this -> _currentSudoku[$row][$i] ) != 0
and
( $key = array_search($current, $probable) ) !== false
)
unset ($probable[$key]);

// find the start of the 3x3 grid with $row x $col cell
$gridRowStart = $this -> _findGridStart($row);
$gridColStart = $this -> _findGridStart($col);

// loop row through the current 3x3 grid
for ($i = $gridRowStart; $i < $gridRowStart + 3; $i++)

// loop column through the current 3x3 grid
for ($j = $gridColStart; $j < $gridColStart + 3; $j++)

// if the cell $i x $j is solved and the value of
// cell $ix$j is in the $probable array then remove
// that element.
if (
( $current = $this -> _currentSudoku[$i][$j] ) != 0
and
( $key = array_search($current, $probable) ) !== false
)
unset ($probable[$key]);

// Store the rest of the probable values to
// _probable[$row][$col]
$this -> _probable[$row][$col] = array_values($probable);

}

/**
* _findGridStart Method
*
* Find the start of the 3x3 grid in which the value
* comes
*
* @access private
* @param int $value 0-9
* @return int
*/
private function _findGridStart ($value){

// return the start of the current 3x3 grid
return floor( $value / 3 ) * 3;
}
}

/**
* <i>ContinueException</i> class
*
* Extends Exception. Used to throw exception for
* continue the outer most loop.
*
*/
Class ContinueException extends Exception{}

?>
```

Comment: Please include the source code you want reviewed in your post next time, don't just link to it.

Comment: And make sure you maintain correct indentation. It's painful to read all starting in the first column.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a few comments on the code rather than the algorithm - I'll leave that to someone else :)

**Commenting**

- Quite a few comments repeat what the code does. For example:

  ```
  // initially set the $probable as array 1 to 9.  
  $probable = range(1,9);
  ```
- There are a few spelling/grammatical mistakes in your comments and function names

  - Weather should be whether.
  - completly should be completely
  - confilicting should be conflicting
  - _findPosibilites() should be _findPossibilities()

**For loops**

- for loops in _findAllProbables and _updateSolved don't have braces. I think it'd be more readable and less liable to introducing bugs if you put braces in; especially on nested for loops.

**Input**

How come you've separated input and solve? Is there any case where you'd want to call one without the other? What happens if you call solve when there isn't any input given? A better interface in my opinion would be:

```
  solve($input)
```

**_checkAllSolved**

Would this be better returning a boolean?  You could then get rid of the `$this->_solved` I think. You should certainly return earlier on ln. 268. In fact wouldn't it be better to just store the number you have solved?

Hope that helps.